# Google Cloud App Engine deploy of java app fails

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy sample java app (`\java-docs-samples\flexible\helloworld`) to my GCP App Engine project. Source is on my laptop, and I have built the project locally.

The error indicates a build is being attempted. I have also moved `app.yaml` to the project root directory - no help. All I need is for the `.war` file to be uploaded.  Any ideas?

My command line to deploy:

```
gcloud app deploy src\main\appengine\app.yaml  --project=my-real-project-name
```

From error log:

```
Pulling image: gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:b279f7e1075a502c04115c15412df5616b9d0e6e9906ed6fc6e426e0bb9602ec
sha256:b279f7e1075a502c04115c15412df5616b9d0e6e9906ed6fc6e426e0bb9602ec: Pulling from gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder
Digest: sha256:b279f7e1075a502c04115c15412df5616b9d0e6e9906ed6fc6e426e0bb9602ec
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gcp-runtimes/java/runtime-builder@sha256:b279f7e1075a502c04115c15412df5616b9d0e6e9906ed6fc6e426e0bb9602ec
Exception in thread "main" com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.exception.ArtifactNotFoundException: No deployable artifacts were found. Unable to proceed.
at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.getArtifact(PrebuiltRuntimeImageBuildStep.java:77)
at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.buildsteps.RuntimeImageBuildStep.run(RuntimeImageBuildStep.java:50)
at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.BuildPipelineConfigurator.generateDockerResources(BuildPipelineConfigurator.java:104)
at com.google.cloud.runtimes.builder.Application.main(Application.java:147)
```

Comment: Have you updated your gcloud sdk? Try running mvn clean install to update the dependencies before deploying.

Comment: Have you been able to run the project locally using the AppEngine local development server? `dev_appserver.py [PATH_TO_YOUR_APP]` or `dev_appserver.py app.yaml` ? because if it works there, then it should usually deploy just fine

Answer (score 3):

You can try with `mvn clean package appengine:deploy` to clean the files and directories generated by Maven during its build.

The difference between the `gcloud app deploy` command and the maven deploy is that the maven builds and packages your app before deploying it and the gcloud command just deploys your application without packaging it. Also, the gcloud command requires you to specify the documents that you are going to deploy.

In the official documentation [[1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-jetty9#deploying_your_app)] [[2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-maven#building_and_deploying_your_app)] you can find more information about how to deploy your application using each command.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps to deplow to google cloud appengine flexible environment:

-Change your war file to jar. see docs below

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only#prerequisites

-Put your jar file in the project root directory (projectName/file.jar).

-Run "gcloud app deploy" from your project directory. see documentation below

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/dev-java-only#deploying_your_app